# Using fputs with an argument of type string

Tags: c++, file, omnet++

I'm using fputs in C++ to write a string in a file.

```
fputs (const char*, FILE*);
```

If I use a simple statement like,

`fputs ("information", pFile);`

everything is ok and "information" will be written in the file. But if I write a variable of type,

`std::vector<std::string>`

into the file, some non-ascii characters are stored in the file. Do I have to use a method to convert type `std::vector<std::string>` into a format which fputs can recognize ?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to be using `fputs` in a C++ program? If not you should probably be using the C++ iostream facilities rather than C functions. If you do have a good reason, then adding it to the question will probably get you better responses.

Comment: I'm coding in OMNET++ simulator. I only found the C code for accessing files. Maybe if I search more thoroughly I could find the headers for accessing files in C++.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
fprintf ( pFile, "%s", iterVar.at(currentRun).c_str() )
```

instead of

```
fprintf ( pFile, "%s", iterVar.at(currentRun).data() )
```

You don't want to use `data()` ever as it is missing the trailing `\0`.

(This code is based on the questioner's comment on @GregHewgill's answer, where `iterVar` is of type `vector<string>`.)

Comment: thanks Aaron McDaid, but I tried both c_str() and data() in my code. they both show unrecognizable characters like this !!

èڑ»iىê«‎ےےے

Comment: The problem is probably somewhere else. You'll need to give us a lot more information. Maybe you have put incorrect data *into* the vector?

Answer (score 3):

That correct, `fputs` does not understand how a `std::vector` is laid out in memory.

You should actually have got a compile error when you tried to pass a `std::vector` to `fputs()`. Did you try to work around the error by adding a cast or something?

Comment: yes you are right, but I used at() to get the string in a specific location of the vector. I mean:
std::vector<std::string> iterVar = ...
fprintf ( pFile, "%s", iterVar.at(currentRun).data() );

Comment: `fputs()` also does not know how to write `std::string` values. Since you're using C++, you should be using iostreams anyway. This could work: `pFile << iterVar.at(currentRun);` (as long as `pFile` is an appropriate kind of `std::ostream`).

Comment: @ManiAm, a `std::string` is not a `char *` either.